# 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' error during implementing Knowledge Distilation using BanglaBERT

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I was trying to implement Knowledge Distilation using pretrained BanglaBERT model. That's why I have created a Distiller() class which extends keras.Models() class. I have defined a function named preprocess_data() which is a helper function that will do preprocessing on training data. Now, the problem is, when it tries to extract string values from the tensor using "new_text = [text.numpy().decode('utf-8')]" this line of code, it throughs an error which is "'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'". The tensor type is 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor' while running the program in google colab. 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor' type tensor does not have numpy attribute to extract value from tensor. I have tried to convert 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor' type tensor into 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' type tensor using 'text = tf.convert_to_tensor(text)' this line of code because 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' type tensor has numpy attribute which can be used to extract values from the tensor. But it didn't work.

class Distiller(keras.Model):
def **init**(self, student, teacher, tokenizer, onehot_encoder, max_len_pad):
super().**init**()
self.teacher = teacher
self.student = student
self.max_len_pad = max_len_pad
self.tokenizer = tokenizer
self.onehot_encoder = onehot_encoder

```
def compile(self, optimizer, metrics, student_loss_fn, distillation_loss_fn, alpha=0.1, temperature=3,):
    super().compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
    self.student_loss_fn = student_loss_fn
    self.distillation_loss_fn = distillation_loss_fn
    self.alpha = alpha
    self.temperature = temperature

# function for preprocessing
def preprocess_data(self, text, label):
    print(type(text))
    text = tf.convert_to_tensor(text)
    new_text = [text.numpy().decode('utf-8')]
    seq = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])[0]
    seq_max = max(seq)
    seq_norm = []
    for x in seq:
      seq_norm.append(x/seq_max)
    seq_norm = pad_sequences(seq_norm, padding='post', maxlen=self.max_len_pad, dtype='float32')
    onehot_label = self.onehot_encoder.transform(label)
    return (seq_norm, label)

def train_step(self, data):
    # Unpack data
    text, label = data
    x, y = self.preprocess_data(text, label)

    # preparing teacher data
    dic = {
        'sentences': text,
        'label': label
    }
    teacher_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)

    # Forward pass of teacher
    teacher_result, teacher_model_output, teacher_wrong_prediction = self.teacher.eval_model(teacher_data)
    teacher_predictions = tf.nn.softmax(teacher_model_output)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Forward pass of student
        student_predictions = self.student(x, training=True)

        # Compute losses
        student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)

        # Compute scaled distillation loss from https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02531
        # The magnitudes of the gradients produced by the soft targets scale
        # as 1/T^2, multiply them by T^2 when using both hard and soft targets.
        distillation_loss = (
            self.distillation_loss_fn(
                tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
            )
            * self.temperature**2
        )

        loss = self.alpha * student_loss + (1 - self.alpha) * distillation_loss

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.student.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

    # Update the metrics configured in `compile()`.
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions)

    # Return a dict of performance
    results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    results.update(
        {"student_loss": student_loss, "distillation_loss": distillation_loss}
    )
    return results

def test_step(self, data):
    # Unpack the data
    x, y = data

    # Compute predictions
    y_prediction = self.student(x, training=False)

    # Calculate the loss
    student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, y_prediction)

    # Update the metrics.
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_prediction)

    # Return a dict of performance
    results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    results.update({"student_loss": student_loss})
    return results
```

Comment: A TF Tensor represents an object in a computational graph and holds no real value until it gets computed. An EagerTensor's value has already been computed. What is the type of `text` before it gets converted to a tensor? Seems like you convert it to a Tensor before trying to get the numpy values.

Comment: Before passing texts into the fit() function to train the model through Knowledge Distillation, I have extracted text sequences and corresponding labels from a pandas DataFrame. After extracting the texts I it was in numpy.str_ type and it was in shape (2059, ). Then I have changed the shape into (2059, 1). Then I have checked the text type it was in numpy.ndarray type.

Comment: Did you try not to do the `text = tf.convert_to_tensor(text)` call, or do it at least a bit later?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it didn't solve the issue.